# How to understand the conditions under which the error occurs (StackTrace wp7)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, stack-trace

How do I read the following stacktrace from the AppHub?

```
Frame    Image             Function                                                         Offset
0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                               19
1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                     520892
2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                     461967
3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                     534468
4                          TransitionStub                                                   0
5                          MyPlayer.AudioPivot.m_wcGetAudio_DownloadStringCompleted    172
6                          System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted                   88
7                          System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted            96
8        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                     507848
9        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                     184683
10       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                     183987
11                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke               112
12                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke               1576
13                         System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke                              104
14                         System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne                                 564
15                         System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl                       84
16                         System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke              80
17                         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch                     404
18                         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke                     56
19                         System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke                     84
```

Code:

```
private WebClient m_wcGetAudio;
private void GetUserData()
{
    if (m_wcGetAudio == null)
    {
        m_wcGetAudio = new WebClient();
        m_wcGetAudio.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(m_wcGetAudio_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }
    try
    {
        m_wcGetAudio.DownloadStringAsync(Login.GetAudioUri(App.AccessToken, App.IdUser));

    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        //UpdateUIStatus("Could not load user data", eX.Message);
    }
}
```

and:

```
void m_wcGetAudio_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        //UpdateUIStatus("Error loading user data", e.Error.Message);
        return;
    }
    var response = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
    if (response["response"].HasValues)
    {
        //Parse Code
    }

    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

My WebClient simply get JSON response, and parses it. There's no handling of cookies. 
So I do not understand why the StackTrace contains:

```
System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke
```

Comment: Seriously, don't use Google Translate for writing questions.

Answer (score 3):

Use a try/catch block in `m_wcGetAudio_DownloadStringCompleted` and handle the exception there in the future, rather than letting it crash your app entirely.

```
try
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        //UpdateUIStatus("Error loading user data", e.Error.Message);
        return;
    }
    var response = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
    if (response["response"].HasValues)
    {
        //Parse Code
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    UpdateUIStatus("Could not load user data", ex.Message);
    // Logger.LogError(ex);
}
```

Comment: The fact is that when I was a father-in application on the phone or the emulator, I would not fly the same mistake .... but here after, that as published it in the Marketplace, a few days there is a list StackTrace .... here and there this error .... and not quite clear at what point and under what conditions they are ...

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a comment.  @arsenium: In general with exception handling code, I recommend you use `ex.ToString()` rather than `ex.Message`, if you can handle the extra lines.  If not, log `ex.ToString()` somewhere as well as displaying `ex.Message` on a status control.  Losing the stack trace makes the error much less useful.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham this is the answer for `how to understand at what point and under what uslovihya there was this error?`

Comment: @UnhandledException: "and if you get any error update question with that" isn't an answer, it is a request for more information.  The OP may have asked inadvertently how to debug the problem, but as far as I can tell they want to know why the problem is happening to begin with.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I'm trying to help him, not just for a up vote. since OP not handled exceptions I show him where he need to change. if any exceptions found he can update the question and others also can help.

Comment: @UnhandledException: I didn't down-vote for exactly that reason.  I'm just saying this is a comment, not an answer.  One reason to delete this (whenever you decide to - maybe once the OP has complied) is that unanswered questions can show up under more question filters.  They might also get higher priority (not sure).

Comment: Actually @UnhandledException solved the problem as well. The problem is related to a invalid result from the WebRequest, causing the JSON parsing to fail. That often happens if the user had a unstable internet connection, or similar. So the solution is actually to wrap the JSON parsing in a try/catch, and handle the error.

Comment: @Claus, UnhandledException: This makes more sense to me.  Upvoting the edited answer.

Comment: you are reading the exception right. The error seem to have occurred in the ondownloadedcompleted. I would check if e.result != null and response has a entry for "response".